# Nginx unit not working with django (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings')

Tags: python, django, nginx-unit

I keep getting: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings' in the unit error logs when trying to add new configuration.

**Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'**

```
2020/12/31 19:51:50 [notice] 13294#13294 process 13297 exited with code 0
2020/12/31 19:51:50 [info] 15500#15500 discovery started
2020/12/31 19:51:50 [notice] 15500#15500 module: java 11.0.8 "/usr/lib/unit/modules/java11.unit.so"
2020/12/31 19:51:50 [notice] 15500#15500 module: perl 5.26.1 "/usr/lib/unit/modules/perl.unit.so"
2020/12/31 19:51:50 [notice] 15500#15500 module: php 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.6 "/usr/lib/unit/modules/php.unit.so"
2020/12/31 19:51:50 [notice] 15500#15500 module: python 2.7.17 "/usr/lib/unit/modules/python2.7.unit.so"
2020/12/31 19:51:50 [notice] 15500#15500 module: python 3.6.9 "/usr/lib/unit/modules/python3.6.unit.so"
2020/12/31 19:51:50 [notice] 15500#15500 module: python 3.7.5 "/usr/lib/unit/modules/python3.7.unit.so"
2020/12/31 19:51:50 [notice] 15500#15500 module: ruby 2.5.1 "/usr/lib/unit/modules/ruby.unit.so"
2020/12/31 19:51:50 [info] 15499#15499 controller started
2020/12/31 19:51:50 [notice] 15499#15499 process 15500 exited with code 0
2020/12/31 19:51:50 [info] 15514#15514 router started
2020/12/31 19:51:50 [info] 15514#15514 OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018, 1010100f
2020/12/31 19:52:40 [info] 15597#15597 "example_python" application started
2020/12/31 19:52:40 [info] 15602#15602 "example_python" application started
2020/12/31 19:54:20 [info] 15766#15766 "example_python" application started
2020/12/31 19:54:20 [info] 15767#15767 "example_python" application started
2020/12/31 19:54:20 [notice] 15499#15499 process 15597 exited with code 0
2020/12/31 19:54:20 [notice] 15499#15499 process 15602 exited with code 0
2020/12/31 19:57:49 [info] 16117#16117 "django" application started
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007f64d9a9ad80 (most recent call first):
2020/12/31 19:57:49 [alert] 15499#15499 process 16117 exited on signal 6 (core dumped)
2020/12/31 19:57:49 [warn] 15514#15514 failed to start application "django"
2020/12/31 19:57:49 [alert] 15514#15514 failed to apply new conf
```

```
sudo curl -X PUT --data-binary @unit.config --unix-socket /var/run/control.unit.sock http://localhost/config
```

unit.config

````
    "applications": {
        "django": {
            "type": "python 3.7",
            "user": "deepak",
            "group": "deepak",
            "path": "/home/deepak/PycharmProjects/project/venv",
            "home": "/home/deepak/PycharmProjects/project",
            "module": "wsgi",
            "environment": {
                "DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE": "project.settings",
                "DB_ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql",
                "DB_NAME": "project",
                "DB_HOST": "127.0.0.1",
                "DB_PORT": "5434"
            }
        }
    },

    "listeners": {
        "*:8400": {
            "pass": "applications/django"
        }
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

In your .json file I see `"type": "python 3.7"`

Seems like you created *.venv* from other version of python, for example *python3.6*

Create .venv from version *3.7*, that may solve the problem.